# How can I store 101011010 to array respectively?

Tags: c++, arrays

for example

if I enter a number like 101011010

> input]
>
> 101011010

I want to store the number to an array like below

> result]
>
> array[0] = 1   array[1] = 0   array[2] = 1   array[3] = 0   array[4] = 1
>   array[5] = 1 ...

I know how to declare array or for loops. It seems like there's some kind of
functions that can help me in C++ library..=(

Comment: @Tacocat C++ is case sensitive. And type casting from `char` to `int` will end up with the coding of the character, not the interpreted number.

Comment: Good point. My bad. I forgot about that -_- @Nicky C

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to convert a char holding a digit to the actual digit is the one already mentioned in other responses:

```
char ch = '3';
int number = ch - '0';
```

This works because the digit characters have consecutive codes in the ASCII table.

If you have a string containing digits and you want to extract all these digits into an array, you have a few options, depending on how much C++ you actually want to use/learn.

**Use a C style array**

```
std::string str = "101011010";

// you must be sure somehow that the array is big enough
int arr[100] = { 0 };
for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
{
    arr[i] = str[i] - '0';        
}
```

You have to correctly manage the size of that C-style array.

**Actually start using C++ and not just C**

```
std::vector<int> arr (str.size());
for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
{
    arr[i] = str[i] - '0';
}
```

An `std::vector` is much easier to use, you don't have to know it's (maximum) size at compile time.

**Some more C++, even some C++11**

```
std::vector<int> arr (str.size());

std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), arr.begin(), 
            [](std::string::value_type ch) { return (ch - '0'); });
```

**Some more C++11, and compile time array size, in case you missed it from 1.**

```
std::array<int, 16> arr;

std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), arr.begin(), 
            [](std::string::value_type ch) { return (ch - '0'); });
```

Like in the first case, the size of the array is `constexpr` so you have to know the maximum length of the string and be careful not to write more than the array size. Unlike a C-style array, `std::array` has a method `at()` that does bounds checking and throws an exception if you're trying to access elements outside the array size.

Comment: ["Portable programs should never call this function with an argument n that is out of range, since this causes undefined behavior."](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5B%5D/) Better use `vector::push_back()` instead of the access operator.

Comment: One should not use it **with an out of range parameter**, not avoid it completely. In the above cases I construct the vectors with an initial number of elements that matches the size of the string, so the indexing doesn't go out of range. Afterwards I just update the elements that have already been created by the constructor.

Comment: I agree it is completely safe with this caution in vector size. But for the sake of habit building, I still prefer `vector::reserve` together with `vector::push_back` or `back_inserter`.